# AWS Device farm Not able to upload the test as error coming 'Could not find test jar'

Tags: exec-maven-plugin, aws-device-farm

I am trying to upload a test using maven on AWS device farm , But while uploading the test error coming that

"There was a problem processing your file. Could not find test jar."

Have added all the dependencies/jars , don't know why this error is coming .If anyone have solution or idea about this it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please package your tests using the documented instructions for [TestNG](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html) or [JUnit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html). You can also [watch our webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1D8PM9kdsI) that walks through the maven configuration.

The command to use for packaging tests is `mvn clean package --DskipTests=true`.